# Cómo corregir este error con bind en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy aprendiendo a realizar un CRUD con React y en los videos que estoy viendo, muestran que en el constructor se pone el `.bind`, tal como lo tengo aquí en el códgio del componente que deseo cargar:

```
//Importar React.
import React, {Component, Fragment} from "react";

//Importar Estilos.

//Importar componentes.
import Enlaces from './navbar';

class Insertar extends Component {

    constructor(props){

        super(props);

        this.onChangeNombres = this.onChangeNombres.bind(this);
        this.onChangeApellidos = this.onChangeApellidos.bind(this);
        this.onChangeCorreo = this.onChangeCorreo.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = {

            nombre: '',
            apellido: '',
            correo: ''

        }

    }

    onChangeNombres(e) {

        this.setState({

            nombre: e.target.value

        });

    }

    onChangeApellidos(e) {

        this.setState({

            apellido: e.target.value

        });

    }

    onChangeCorreo(e) {

        this.setState({

            correo: e.target.value

        });

    }

    render(){

        return(

            <Fragment>

                <Enlaces/>

                <div className="container" style={{marginTop: 10}}>

                    <h3>Agregar nuevo usuario</h3>

                    <br/>

                    <form>

                        <div className="form-group">

                            <label for="nombreUsuario">Nombres:</label>

                            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="nombreUsuario" id="nombreUsuario" placeholder="Nombres del usuario..." value={this.state.nombre} onChange={this.onChangeNombres} />

                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">

                            <label for="apellidoUsuario">Apellidos:</label>

                            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="apellidoUsuario" id="apellidoUsuario" placeholder="Apellidos del usuario..." value={this.state.apellido} onChange={this.onChangeApellidos} />

                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">

                            <label for="correoUsuario">Correo electrónico:</label>

                            <input type="email" className="form-control" name="correoUsuario" id="correoUsuario" placeholder="Correo electrónico del usuario..." value={this.state.correo} onChange={this.onChangeCorreo} />

                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">

                            <button type="submit" value="Regitrar" name="botonRegistrar" className="btn btn-success">Subir</button>

                        </div>

                    </form>

                </div>

            </Fragment>

        );

    }

}

export default Insertar;
```

Y este es el error que me arroja:

[image: Imagen del error arrojado por React.]

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
```

Por favor, agradecería mucho la ayuda ya que no sé cómo se podría hacer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para no complicarte la vida con `.bind` te recomiendo usar siempre arrow functions. De esta forma no necesitas hacer `.bind` a cada funcion, te ahorras lineas de codigo y es mas sencillo para vos.

Ejemplo:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            nombre: '',
            apellido: '',
            correo: ''
        }

    }

......

onChangeNombres = (e) => {

        this.setState({

            nombre: e.target.value

        });

    }

render(){

        return(
            .......

            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="nombreUsuario" id="nombreUsuario" placeholder="Nombres del usuario..." value={this.state.nombre} onChange={this.onChangeNombres} />
           ........
        )
}
```

Si haces esto mismo para cada funcion, como ves en el ejemplo, no hace falta inicializar todas las funciones en el constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Te falla porque en tu componente no tienes definido ningún método que se llame `onSubmit` por eso te da el error al hacer `bind`.

Para corregir basta con crear el método `onSubmit` en la clase `Insertar`.

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from "react";

//Importar Estilos.

//Importar componentes.
import Enlaces from './navbar';

class Insertar extends Component {

    constructor(props){

        super(props);

        this.onChangeNombres = this.onChangeNombres.bind(this);
        this.onChangeApellidos = this.onChangeApellidos.bind(this);
        this.onChangeCorreo = this.onChangeCorreo.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = {

            nombre: '',
            apellido: '',
            correo: ''

        }

    }

    onChangeNombres(e) {

        this.setState({

            nombre: e.target.value

        });

    }

    onChangeApellidos(e) {

        this.setState({

            apellido: e.target.value

        });

    }

    onChangeCorreo(e) {

        this.setState({

            correo: e.target.value

        });

    }

    onSubmit() {
        // tu codigo
    }

    render(){

        return(

            <Fragment>

                <Enlaces/>

                <div className="container" style={{marginTop: 10}}>

                    <h3>Agregar nuevo usuario</h3>

                    <br/>

                    <form>

                        <div className="form-group">

                            <label for="nombreUsuario">Nombres:</label>

                            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="nombreUsuario" id="nombreUsuario" placeholder="Nombres del usuario..." value={this.state.nombre} onChange={this.onChangeNombres} />

                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">

                            <label for="apellidoUsuario">Apellidos:</label>

                            <input type="text" className="form-control" name="apellidoUsuario" id="apellidoUsuario" placeholder="Apellidos del usuario..." value={this.state.apellido} onChange={this.onChangeApellidos} />

                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">

                            <label for="correoUsuario">Correo electrónico:</label>

                            <input type="email" className="form-control" name="correoUsuario" id="correoUsuario" placeholder="Correo electrónico del usuario..." value={this.state.correo} onChange={this.onChangeCorreo} />

                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">

                            <button type="submit" value="Regitrar" name="botonRegistrar" className="btn btn-success">Subir</button>

                        </div>

                    </form>

                </div>

            </Fragment>

        );

    }

}
```

Comment: otra opcion seria usar arrow functions para evitar hacer el bind en el constructor, `onSubmit = () => { ... }`